# One to many nodes in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to create the following site in Drupal 7, with no success:

- Front page is listing news topics (e.g. election 2012, earthquake in some town). For this I have created content type 'news topic'.
- when I click on the news topic, I can see that it lists following sections: article, video, photo gallery, interview. Eeach of these sections is a different content type.

How can I make one->many (e.g. one news topic has many galleries) relation in Drupal 7?
How can I list all dependent content types on 'news topic' page?
Would it be better if I used Drupal 6?

Comment: why do you think using an earlier version of Drupal would solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Mitch, drupal 7 has only about 30% modules compatible. Drupal 6 has almost 100%, so there is bigger chance the module someone recommends will work with this version..

Answer (score 4):

How about using the 'References' module? You would then first create a couple of galleries. When that's done, you would create the news topic and reference those two galleries from the news topic node.

I haven't tried it myself on Drupal 7, but it works well on Drupal 6.

http://drupal.org/project/references